# Django - Completar select hasta 10 (Tupla + siguientes hasta 10)

Tags: python, django

¿Cómo completar una select de 10 preguntas, si la tupla tiene menos pero la tabla de preguntas tiene cientos:

Ejemplo:
La siguiente tupla tiene 6 números, pero queremos que la consulta haga de esas 6 **+ las siguientes correlativas hasta completar hasta 10 números**.

```
tupla = [1,3,5,7,9,10]
Pregunta.objects.filter(numeroPregunta__in=tupla)[:10]#más siguientes hasta recopilar 10 números
```

El objetivo es que Pregunta consiga: 1,3,5,7,9,10,**11,12,13,14** y no sólo las de la tupla.

Comment: Hola Julian, cómo vas a filtrar que las pregúntas sean las que necesitas.? o que simplemente las rellene con las que sea.?

Comment: Que rellene con los siguientes números correlativos/seguidos/siguientes como en el ejemplo. (No se si me he explicado bien).

Comment: Correlativos o que existan en la tabla.?

Comment: Tienes razón se deben cumplir las dos condiciones, que sean seguidos siempre que existan en la tabla, porque son unas 500 preguntas, si llegaran al final, el programa no sabría que no hay más. Pediría la 501, etc y daría error o vacío.

Comment: Exacto, y en ese caso que deseas hacer.?

Comment: En el caso de que no haya más, debe selecionar las que hay. No 10, sino 9 u 8 o ninguno si no hay más. De hecho cuando se complete todo, debería felicitar al estudiante. xD

Comment: Hahaha entiendo; es decir, va a continuar obteniendo 10 pregúntas hasta llegar a 500. no.?

Comment: Algo que no me queda claro es; De dónde sale la tupla.?

Comment: Eso es, va continuar obteniendo 10 preguntas hasta llegar a 500. Bueno, la tupla recopila números de preguntas que no ha terminado de aprender. Los números que no aparecen son las que el programa las da por aprendidas. Para entender el sistema de aprendizaje es simplemente un pack de 10 preguntas que se le pregunta cíclicamente (son tipo a,b,c,d) que cuando responde correctamente 4 veces seguidas, el programa la da por aprendida y sigue preguntando las siguientes. No es más que eso: Un sistema de aprendizaje con un ciclo de 10 preguntas dando vueltas hasta aprender las 500 preguntas.

Comment: Solo algunas definiciones: en Python una tupla es una lista inmutable no modificable y define entre paréntesis. Una lista  es parecida al a tupla pero sus elementos son modificables. Se define entre corchetes.  En tu problema realmente defines una lista no una tupla. Quizá este pequeño detalle pueda traerte dificultades más adelante si no tienes claro entre tupla y lista.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich tienes toda la razón, incluso yo estuve llamando tupla a la lista (de vez en cuanto me confundo), muy mal hecho por mi parte. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías obtener la cantidad de preguntas faltantes proximas a la ultima pregúnta de la tupla, prueba lo siguiente:

```
#EVITO TENER UNA TUPLA VACÍA
if len(tupla)>0:
    tupla=[0]

nuevas_preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(numeroPregunta__lt=tupla[-1])[:10-len(tupla)]

for p in nuevas_preguntas.values(): 
    tupla.append(p.get("numeroPregunta"))

Pregunta.objects.filter(numeroPregunta__in=tupla)
```

Espero funcione y te sea útil.

Comment: Te sugiero verificar que la tupla no tenga más de 10 elementos para evitar errores.